# cgi-bin ScriptAlias on difference directory

Tags: apache, cgi, httpd.conf

please help me to resolve this problem!

Currently i have a server with 2 HDDs mounted as /site01 and /site02 and i've created 2 sites on each HDDs.

And now i would like to run cgi script on both sites but i don't know how to config the ScriptAlias for the cgi-bin directory. The cgi script is placed on /site01/www/cgi-bin for site01.mydomain.com and /site02/www/cgi-bin for site02.mydomain.com.

Right now my httpd.conf configured as:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /site01/www/cgi-bin/
```

And with this i can execute cgi script on site01.mydomain.com But how do i configure for the script on the site02.mydomain.com to run this too?

I have tried to put:

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /*/www/cgi-bin/
```

or

```
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /site0*/www/cgi-bin/
```

But it's not possible to run.

Answer (score 0):

The ScriptAlias directive can be placed inside the VirtualHost directive. By having different ScriptAlias directives in each of you VirtualHosts, you can specify different script directories for you sites.